# How can I create a recurrent tasks in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, cron, architecture

For one of my project, I need to create a task that updates the status of cars when they are late.
They are considered late when they exceed their schedule time.

So, I would like to know what is the best solution to do this.

Should I create a job that run every minute ? Or are there better solution that are less resources expensive ?

Comment: And what for? You have schedule time and current time... You can always calculate when late if needed on client

Comment: I need to see the schedule in real time, so when it doesn't arrive on time, the user must be able to see it.

Comment: see where ? update where ?

Comment: In my application that will be developed in react

Comment: Then why it has C# tag ? As I wrote do it on client side ... In server/DB do not update

Comment: I think this is a task that should be done by the backend, right?                                        To be able to change the status when the truck is late?

Comment: And what for? You have schedule time and current time... you can always calculate when its late if needed on client (yes, I wrote it again because it seems like you didn't read it) you may have arrivaltime and only update this when car finally arrives, so you can tell that it was late but before it arrives you should take current time difference with schedule time on some time tick, EOT

Comment: We would like to have a delayed status in our DB because later we would like to do reporting.  Doing calculations to find out if it is late could be a bit more complicated for reporting, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the question, one of the solutions could be to use a scheduler like Quartz.net (https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

You did not present a lot of detail on the problem itself, so i am assuming that you are doing something like lending the car for someone and they have a time limit.

Since that information was not provided, there are a lot of scenarios. Do you really need a scheduler? Do you want to know if they are late when they are delivered/arrive? If so, you probably just need to calculate whenever the delivery/action you are expecting happens.

But, if you really need a scheduler to trigger something, you can use a scheduler.

Quartz.net can be in memory (good for POC purposes: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorial/job-stores.html#ramjobstore), but also in database (so you can share with multiple instances of the same service https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorial/job-stores.html#ado-net-job-store-adojobstore).

You can simply have a job that has arguments (such as the car id), and then reuse the same code. The jobs can be scheduled in several ways, simply datetime (https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html#simple-triggers), or even be recurrent with cron expressions (https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html#example-cron-expressions).

There are other schedulers available, but Quartz.Net was the one i already used in several scenarios, both professionally and personally